# Access parent "this" variables, from inherited class

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance

I know this is simple and it's probably out there some where I'm just not sure what to look for "class inheritance"? I'm trying to access ship's `this` function from within cargo. Ideas?

```
var Ship = function() {
    this.id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);
};

var Cargo = function(){
    this.id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);
}

Cargo.prototype.push = function(string){
    return string;
}

Ship.prototype.cargo = Cargo;

module.exports = Ship;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "ship's `this` function"? The `this` value in `Ship` wouldn't be expected to be a function. The value of `this` is determined by how a function is invoked. There is no static `this` value.

Comment: I need the properties of ship in cargo. Does that make sense?

Comment: after re-reading your question, why would cargo inherit from ship? The domain model doesnt make sense. it makes more sense to use dependency injection (see answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function of the prototype can already access `this` of an instance.

```
var Ship=function () {
    this.id=Math.floor(Math.random()*1000000);
};

var Cargo=function () {
    this.id=Math.floor(Math.random()*1000000);
};

Cargo.prototype.push=function (string) {
    return string;
};

Ship.prototype.cargo=function () {
    var cargo=new Cargo();
    cargo.ship=this;
    return cargo;
};

var ship1=new Ship();
var cargo1=ship1.cargo();
var cargo2=ship1.cargo();
alert(cargo1.ship.id===cargo2.ship.id);

var ship2=new Ship();
var cargo3=ship2.cargo();
var cargo4=ship2.cargo();
alert(cargo3.ship.id===cargo4.ship.id);

alert(cargo1.ship.id===cargo3.ship.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could extend the object either using underscore or mimic its source:

http://underscorejs.org/#extend

http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-78

Edit: i think what you want is this.

```
var Cargo, Ship, cargo;

Ship = (function() {
  function Ship() {}

  return Ship;

})();

Cargo = (function() {
  function Cargo(ship) {
    this.ship = ship;
  }

  return Cargo;

})();

cargo = new Cargo(new Ship());

alert(cargo.ship);
```

Comment: I want all the cargo to share the same ship, this makes a new ship for each cargo.

Comment: var ship = new Ship(); var cargo1 = new Cargo(ship) ; var cargo2 = new Cargo(ship); 

(all the same ship - one way to solve it via dep injection).

Comment: I'd like to not have to include ship in cargo.